# Help me to attach inner ring

Tags: chainring, crankset

I have cranks with 4 holes for outer and middle rings attachment. There are no holed for inner ring attachment. On my other bikes crankset middlering has 8 holes 4 for cranks and 4 for inner ring. I tried to take them and attach to my other outer chainring and cranks and put it on bike, everything works perfect. The problem is I can't find  middle chainring with 8 holes for sale in my country or on ebay. Should I drill 4 more holes on my crank. Or what should I do please advise!

Some IMGS:

I. My other middle chainring with 8 holes, I can't find it for sale:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsnRM.jpg]

II. My crank inner side with 4 places for drilling maybe :D

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWSiX.jpg]

Comment: What brand cranks are you swapping parts from.

Comment: Wow I've never seen an inner attached to a middle like that. It does look like the 4 posts/blanks in the spider are exactly where you would usually find inner ring holes. As Mikes says, we need to know the chain set brand (or bike brand)

Answer (score 1):

I dont remember how did I connected here yesterday, so now I writing connected with gmail with my phone.
Anyways, I took 32T attached to 22T from XCT SR SUNTOUR V3 22t,32t,42t crankset, I bought it from ebay, sorry cant give you the link now. Cranks with 4 holes only are FSA alphadrive. XCT also has 4 holes only on crank.

EDIT: cranks with middle chainring which has 8 holes.: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/280915668543?ssPageName=STRK:MEWAX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1423.l2649